# What is the best way for applications to communicate in micro-service architectures

Tags: python, json, xml-rpc, microservices, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have to design and implement a service delivery platform.  I have various services in my current design and all of those tools are using different technologies.  Some are erlang based concurrent map-reduce functions and some are simple bash scripts to aggregate some text files.

I heard about **XML/RPC**, **Protocol Buffer**, **message-pack**, **soup** and **AMQP**.  currently I use **JSON**, but loading and dumping large json files are a bit time/memory consuming.  Is there any new or robust way to make a bridge between various technologies on HTTP infrastructure with wide range programming language support and well documentation?

I also need to mention that i believe complexity is much more corrosive than latency problems or other connection related issues.  So the JSON replacement must not add complexity to design.

Comment: if your JSON file will be large, you are guaranteed to suffer the penalty from HTTP latency anyway. Are the service calls going to change dynamically and very frequently?

Comment: yes, for example, Authorization service will be called 2 million times a day.
and not all json files, but some of them are large.

Comment: if your stack is bound to HTTP infrastructure, my gut feeling is that you'd better go with a database (NoSQL) as a communication platform, with eventual consistency, caching and async service calls to minimize the bottleneck. Of course I'm not familiar to what exactly your micro-services do so this is just an option for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks @Anzel, The main problem is the communication protocol.  I am happy with json but out of curiosity, I am looking for new techniques.

Comment: Not a problem, FYI, "one" communication protocol won't be enough if your micro-services will each rely on not only 1 another service (or partially), ie. you will have to deal with queuing, race condition and I/O etc... which IMHO it's more about a communication strategy than protocol. Anyhow, good luck and all the best ;)

Comment: I am solving the race condition problem with a workflow engine (again as a service).  Every process that takes more than 500ms will be send to a workflow engine and it's state will be saved and the original service will be notified using callbacks.  But you are right.  My question is communication strategy rather than protocol

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to persist your data, you could also take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/) and its pubsub features. It is mature, really simple to configure and use, great documentation and a big community.

Here's a list of available client libraries (5 Erlang libs for example)
http://redis.io/clients